# Talend - how to run a block of components in a loop?

Tags: talend

Can you please advise how to run the following block of components in a loop?
I highlighted the portion of the URL that I need to iterate:
It should be: `context.startIndex`*1, `context.startIndex`*2, `context.startIndex`*3...etc, etc, up to 100.

Is it possible to use a tLoop? Please provide a description of the method.

Thank you,
Mircea

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do so, just by adding a tLoop after the onComponentOK link, and connect components like this :

```
 tLoop --iterate--> tFixedFlowInput --main--> tRestClient
```

(tFixedFlow is just here to let you connect tLoop to tRestClient)

Basic settings in tLoop : from/to/step : 1/100/1
In your tRestComponent, you should use the globalMap variable provided by your tLoopComponent :

```
..startIndex="+context.startIndex*((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_ITERATION"))
```

Use the 'Outline' view to get the global variables you can access with your components.

Comment: instead of using an oncomponent ok before the restclient use the itrate link of the loop, and btw you should always aim for using onsubjob ok links.

Comment: @M.R. : you are correct, you need a component between tLoop and tRestClient. You can use a tFixedFlow for example. I have edited my answer

Comment: Thank you so much Corentin, I got it working! This saved me tons of work as I am getting ClearQuest information and it can take over 100 iterations. May as ask you one more question, please? At the very end of the iteration loop I want a stored procedure to be executed. How should I link tMSqlLSp_1 to this block of components so that it executes only once?                                                    note: please add an extra "(" to the code, it should be: ..startIndex="+context.startIndex*((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_ITERATION"))

Comment: Also, I noticed that (Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_ITERATION") does not seem to start from 0, it starts from 1 even though I set From=0 in tLoop. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Figured out, set it to start from -1 so that the first iteration is zero